# How to use svg graphic from a website?

Tags: html, svg

I try to use the bell svg graphic from [gutefrage.net](https://www.gutefrage.net/)

[image]

but I don't know how exactly it does work, I tried it like this, but it just displays nothing:

```html
<g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2"><path d="M8 2.5c2 0 4 1.5 4 3.5s0 2.5.5 4.5c.242.97.5 1.5 1 2s1.5 1.5 1.5 2c0 0 0 .5-.5 1s-.5.5-1 .5H8M9 2s0-1-1-1-1 1-1 1M8 2.5C6 2.5 4 4 4 6s0 2.5-.5 4.5c-.243.97-.5 1.5-1 2S1 14 1 14.5c0 0 0 .5.5 1s.5.5 1 .5H8M6 17c0 1.5 1 2 2 2s2-.5 2-2"></path></g>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it in an `svg` tag.

```html
<svg>
  <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2"><path d="M8 2.5c2 0 4 1.5 4 3.5s0 2.5.5 4.5c.242.97.5 1.5 1 2s1.5 1.5 1.5 2c0 0 0 .5-.5 1s-.5.5-1 .5H8M9 2s0-1-1-1-1 1-1 1M8 2.5C6 2.5 4 4 4 6s0 2.5-.5 4.5c-.243.97-.5 1.5-1 2S1 14 1 14.5c0 0 0 .5.5 1s.5.5 1 .5H8M6 17c0 1.5 1 2 2 2s2-.5 2-2"></path></g>
</svg>
```